# 8 bit to 1 byte logic chip

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying read the output of ov7670 camera. To read the output image you must read the value of 8 pins in quick succession, the result of which is byte. This is pretty difficult unless microcontroller reading is fast enough. So, i was curious if there is a logic circuit designed for thus. Reads 8 pins(bits) outputs(serial/spi) a byte. Seems like this would be something needed occasionally with circuits.

Comment: I use a PIC32, which has a parallel master port (used as slave) and then DMA to frame buffer. Other PICs also have parallel slave ports. Which micro are you using?

Comment: Even on 8-bit microcontrollers such as the ATmega series AVRs you are not restricted to reading one pin at a time. For example, on the arduino uno you do not have to execute "bool inN = digitalRead(inputpinN);" eight times, you can read all in parallel with "uint8_t input = PIND;". There is the restriction that you can't use just any pins, you have to connect bit 0 to D0, 1 to D1 ... 7 to D7. You can also do this on C0...C7 and B0...B7, but watch out for pins with predetermined functions such as the crystal pins and the reset pin.

Comment: have you heared of a parallel to serial converter (or shifter) "74LV165"

Comment: @jms, it's called a "port" read. D, C, and B are all port designations. That's all I have to add and your answer was spot on.

Comment: @Dave that would be valid for a PIC, but I used an arduino (usually ATmega328 based) as my example. An AVR has three registers for each IO port: DDRx for selecting if each pin is being driven by the AVR or not. PORTx for setting each pin high or low (when DDRx is set) or enabling the internal 10k pull-up or tri-stating the pin (when DDRx is clear). Reading the value of PORTx doesn't return the logic level input of each pin, it returns what you have previously written into the register. Reading PINx returns the current state of each pin, bur PINx cannot be written to.

Comment: @jms, straight off of the arduino web site "PIND is the input register variable It will read all of the digital input pins at the same time." Thus port read. Link: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation

Comment: @Dave Okay, I got confused by your previous reply. I thought that you meant that in order to get the status of each IO pin, you have to read the PORTx register. Apparently you were arguing about the semantics of IO pins vs ports instead. A port is a group of IO pins that share the same register (or address in memory mapped architectures), I never even disagreed about that.

Comment: @jms, I only posted that comment so that user45454 could look up the concept of PORT I/O on their own and use it to solve the problem. They seem to be stuck on PIN I/O, which arduino is notorious for teaching.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 74HC165.

But I don't think that you will be able to read the camera over a single pin of your uC. If you can not sample the pins fast enough in parallel, it will not work in serial either. Reading a camera without an hardware interface is almost impossible from my experience.

Comment: I think that OP is probably self-imposing a limitation using the arduino or other similar abstraction layer. He said that as he can't successfully read the bits in parallel he wants to try reading them in series, but if my assumption is correct the key is not to add a shift register but to use the native IO of the chip properly for a speed greater by orders of magnitude.

Comment: I would also try to route all bits to a port and read it in once. Still I don't think it is possible to read the port on a external clock signal (multi MHz) fast enough without any (internal) hardware support.

But without the context, this could be a answer to his question

Comment: Thanks for the comments, very interesting, but it sounds like the 74hc165, would be a little slower than what i need. When i started working with the ov7670, i was using arduino amega328. By reading the bits on two ports i was able to capture the data, barely. I have tried using more powerful micros teensy 3 and stm32f429. They work, but i still think there could be a better less expensive solution. This is pretty simple logic, it is just the speed that is a problem. I have seen cplds used, but seems like overkill. What do phone cameras use?

Comment: The stm32f429 has a camera interface! Why not use this? Smartphones use cameras with the CSI2 or 3 interface. This is already serial and very high speed. It has to be connected to a ISP (Image Processor).